# how to create an object without passing arguments in python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-class

I have a function which create object from class type and the content passed in.

```py
def create_from(cls, info):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls)
    obj.load_info(info)
    return obj
```

The reason I use `__new__` here is that the number of arguments need to initialize the object are uncertain.

It works fine for all the class I have except the class I inherit from `asyncio.Future`.

```py
c = asyncio.Future
c.__new__(c)
```

will throw the AttributeError says: 'Future' object has no attribute '_callbacks' .

My question are:

1. Is there any better way to this?
2. Why `__new__` in asyncio.Future will throw this error? In my mind, the `__new__` should be called without touch any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I choose to add a method `create_obj` for all the classes will be used in this scenario. By implementing the method for classes inherit from `asyncio.Future` independently, I bypass the problem.

```py
class mySavableFuture(asyncio.Future):

    @classmethod
    def create_obj(cls):
        return cls()

class SavableA():

    @classmethod
    def create_obj(cls):
        return cls.__new__(cls)
```

It is seems like a compromised way, but it works for my now. Expect for better solution.

Comment: That will not work: you missed the `cls` parameter. Note that `__new__` is a static method, not a class method.